# How to know if this filter is causal?

Tags: filter

If I have the following equation: y[n] = 0.5*y[n-1] + x[n]

How do I know if this is a causal filter or not?

Comment: Hi! so, what is the *definition* of "causal"? (this is really easy if just speak out the definition!)

Comment: "The word causal indicates that the filter output depends only on past and present inputs. A filter whose output also depends on future inputs is non-causal, whereas a filter whose output depends only on future inputs is anti-causal".

Comment: exactly! So, what in your formula is the filter output, and what is the input? Does it depend on future input?

Comment: If it's wearing sneakers and blue jeans, then it is casual.  Shirt, tie, and wingtips means "formal."

Comment: Casual != causal.

Comment: @JRE lol, that slipped my attention when reading!

Comment: The input is x[n] and output is y[n]. The only thing I see it's dependent on is the "n" value. But I'm not sure if I'm thinking correctly? I think I would classify this as Causal. And since n is present and n-1 is past values, it should be causal

Wops, meant causal not casual.

Comment: Althrough, it says past and present inputs on wiki. and since x[n] is the output, does y[n-1] still count as an "input" since it's part of the output?

Answer (score 8):

"The word causal indicates that the filter output depends only on past and present inputs. A filter whose output also depends on future inputs is non-causal, whereas a filter whose output depends only on future inputs is anti-causal"

The input is \$x[n]\$ and output is \$y[n]\$.

And since \$n\$ is present and \$n-1\$ is past values, it's causal.

Comment: How could be a filter ever dependent on a future input signal? How could a filter know what signal it has to expect in the future? Please link a filter that can give a future lottery numbers.

Comment: An adaptive kalman filter perhaps? I mean, you can use machine learning and do predictions based on previous values; however, the accuracy of doing this is unclear. Or collect previous data, predict the upcoming data points/signals, and use this inside of a filter. 

But I get your point.

Comment: In image processing, a filter can use the values of the pixels to the left as well as the right of the current pixel. Even though this is not a time axis, the math looks the same as non-causal filters. @MarkoBuršič

Comment: @AJN I see. While I was thinking about a real-time processing, you and OP have in mind about post-processing stored data. So this "future" is just a direction, like from the left to the right, or from the top to the bottom. But common speaking, a future would mean a time that didn't happen yet.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič You could record a sound, and then filter the recording with a non-causal filter. Your filter can see the next part of the recording as well as the previous part.

Comment: @user253751 For example, an automatic gain control filter for pre-recorded audio which takes upcoming volume spikes into account.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič You can also use a delay line. A simple one is a tape recorder with a read and write head a few cm away, but there are others. Radars (and oscilloscopes?) had delay lines that were long tubes with microphones and speakers on opposite ends. Your delay, then, was the length/speed_of_sound. Heck, even a long coil of wire works if you consider impedance effects.

Answer (score 3):

I'll add a bit of pedantry to Eric' answer.

The same difference equation can be written as:

$$
y[n-1] = 2y[n] - 2x[n]
$$

And now you have a non-causal implementation of the same filter (which, by the way, is not BIBO stable).

So a single difference equation will have as many solutions as regions of convergence in the Z-plane (2 in this case due to the single pole).

So, in general, the problem statement will have more information given (explicitly or implicitly), such as causality or stability, which determine the region of convergence to use.

Causal systems have only one solution which corresponds to the outer region of convergence.

Comment: (It's actually Eric's answer.)